# Music Looping BGE

Tags: game-engine

I'm making music for my Blender game. After the song ends, I want it to start or loop from another portion of the song rather than the very beginning. I notice some games do that with music, but is it possible to do that with Blender?

Let's say the song starts off with a drum beat and then a melody later. When the song ends, I want it to start from the melody rather than the drum beat (the very beginning of the song).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, and you should use Python. Example blend file can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tbONa74ee4mrzREJiRs_yzJoDZeOD_oI/view?usp=sharing), the code is fully commented.

Notes:

- I've made this song especially for this answer. ;)
- For moderators: The zip file is needed as I can't pack the music file on blend if I want to load it through Python. It's not possible to upload zip files on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so I posted the example file on my Google Drive. Sorry for the inconvenience.

```py
import bge
import aud
from bge.logic import expandPath, globalDict

# Load music factory to memory at start, if not already
if not 'music' in globalDict.keys():

    # Self explanatory
    music_path = expandPath('//example_music.ogg')

    # Load at globalDict the buffered music factory
    # Buffering allows lower delay on playing a new loop
    globalDict['music'] = aud.Factory(music_path).buffer()

def main(cont):

    own = cont.owner

    # Sensors
    always = cont.sensors[0]

    # Other
    device = aud.device()

    # Constants
    START_POS = 0.0
    LOOP_POS = 8.0

    # If sensor activated and music factory is loaded in globalDict
    if always.positive and 'music' in globalDict.keys():

        # If playback handle is not present in current object
        # After handle is created, this block will not run anymore
        if not 'music' in own:

            # Create a property in current object with playback handle
            own['music'] = device.play(globalDict['music'])

            # Set starting position of first playback
            own['music'].position = START_POS

            # Warning message
            print('Song not playing, playing it from start', START_POS)

        # If playback handle is present in current object
        if 'music' in own:

            # If music stopped playing
            if own['music'].status == False:

                # Play and save a new handle in place of the older one
                own['music'] = device.play(globalDict['music'])

                # Set starting position of loop playback
                own['music'].position = LOOP_POS

                # Warning message
                print('Loop song at position', LOOP_POS)
```